# spring rest api deploy to websphere

Tags: spring, rest, websphere

We have an old legacy application which we package as ear and deploy to websphere. Trying to find ways to use spring rest api and create service end points in this app. I have seen some examples online which return as spring mvc view-model but how will the consumer consume the jsp. I dont like this approach. I would like it to return like any spring boot application. Please note this is not a spring boot application but built on old spring framework.